# How to deploy a Node app to an Azure Web App without the Node Modules?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm pushing a React application to an Azure Web App from VS2017, and would like for it to upload without the actual modules, just the package.json, then pull the packages once it's in the cloud. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you pulling from a git repo or uploading straight from your machine?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda for the first upload, straight from the machine. Once that works, I'll be using continuous integration with a git repo.

Comment: Hmm, multiple ways to do it. You can delete `node_modules` on the server when you go to deploy or you can add `node_modules` to your .gitignore file and pull straight from git. Where do you run `npm install` when you deploy your app? You should remove the `node_modules` folder right before you do that.